# How to keep the playback speed when clicking the pause button and then when continuing playing?

Tags: c#, winforms, opencv, user-interface

inside the btnPause click event in the continue part in the original it was:

```
await Task.Delay(playbackSpeed);
```

but I used a breakpoint and see that while it's playing the frames when I keep clicking the play button btnPlay the playback speed is increasing the playing is getting faster and faster and this is what it will be the behavior in the play button btnPlay but the playbackSpeed remain the same value.

so when the playback speed increased when i click the pause button then continue it will continue playing it in the same original speed and not the current speed.

so I tried in the continue part to change it to:

```
await Task.Delay(1000 / (int)videoCapture.Fps);
```

but then I noticed that the Fps never change even if i click the play button many times and the playback speed was increasing.  the Fps stay the same value.

so last thing I tried was adding the local variable playbackSpeedMultiplier and calulating the speed when continuing but this is not working either and it keep playing the original speed when clicking to continue.

```
else if (btnPause.Text == "Continue")
    {
        // Continue playing the video from the current frame
        isVideoPlaying = true;

        // Change button text to Pause
        btnPause.Text = "Pause";

        // Start the playback loop
        double playbackSpeedMultiplier = 1.0; // Default multiplier
        while (videoCapture.PosFrames < trackBarFrames.Maximum && isVideoPlaying)
        {
            LoadAndDisplayFrame();
            trackBarFrames.Value = (int)videoCapture.PosFrames;

            // Dynamically calculate the delay based on the current frames per second and the multiplier
            await Task.Delay((int)(1000 / (int)videoCapture.Fps * playbackSpeedMultiplier));
        }
        isVideoPlaying = false;
    }
```

this is the full code.

```
using OpenCvSharp;
using OpenCvSharp.Extensions;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Lightnings_Detector
{
    public partial class VideoEditor : Form
    {
        private readonly VideoCapture videoCapture;
        private readonly VideoWriter videoWriter;
        private readonly Mat currentFrame = new Mat();
        private bool isVideoPlaying = false;
        private int playbackSpeed = 1000 / 30; // Default playback speed in milliseconds per frame

        public VideoEditor(VideoCapture videoCapture, VideoWriter videoWriter)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.videoCapture = videoCapture ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(videoCapture));
            this.videoWriter = videoWriter ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(videoWriter));

            InitializeVideoPlayer();
        }

        private void InitializeVideoPlayer()
        {
            // Set trackbar range
            trackBarFrames.Maximum = (int)videoCapture.Get(VideoCaptureProperties.FrameCount) - 1;

            // Display video properties
            labelVideoProperties.Text = $"Video Properties: {videoCapture.FrameWidth}x{videoCapture.FrameHeight}, {videoCapture.Fps} fps, {videoCapture.FrameCount} frames";

            // Load and display the initial frame
            LoadAndDisplayFrame();
        }

        private void LoadAndDisplayFrame()
        {
            videoCapture.Read(currentFrame);
            if (!currentFrame.Empty())
            {
                pictureBoxPlayer.Image = currentFrame.ToBitmap();
                labelCurrentFrame.Text = $"Current Frame: {videoCapture.PosFrames}/{trackBarFrames.Maximum}";
            }
        }

        private void VideoEditor_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void trackBarFrames_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelCurrentFrame.Text = $"Current Frame: {trackBarFrames.Value}";

            // Navigate to the selected frame
            videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.PosFrames, trackBarFrames.Value);
            LoadAndDisplayFrame();
        }

        private async void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isVideoPlaying = true;
            while (videoCapture.PosFrames < trackBarFrames.Maximum && isVideoPlaying)
            {
                LoadAndDisplayFrame();
                trackBarFrames.Value = (int)videoCapture.PosFrames;
                await Task.Delay(playbackSpeed);
            }
            isVideoPlaying = false;
        }

        private async void btnPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (btnPause.Text == "Pause")
            {
                // Pause the video playback
                isVideoPlaying = false;

                // Change button text to Continue
                btnPause.Text = "Continue";
            }
            else if (btnPause.Text == "Continue")
            {
                // Continue playing the video from the current frame
                isVideoPlaying = true;

                // Change button text to Pause
                btnPause.Text = "Pause";

                // Start the playback loop
                double playbackSpeedMultiplier = 1.0; // Default multiplier
                while (videoCapture.PosFrames < trackBarFrames.Maximum && isVideoPlaying)
                {
                    LoadAndDisplayFrame();
                    trackBarFrames.Value = (int)videoCapture.PosFrames;

                    // Dynamically calculate the delay based on the current frames per second and the multiplier
                    await Task.Delay((int)(1000 / (int)videoCapture.Fps * playbackSpeedMultiplier));
                }
                isVideoPlaying = false;
            }
        }

        private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop the video playback
            isVideoPlaying = false;

            // Set the position to the beginning
            videoCapture.Set(VideoCaptureProperties.PosFrames, 0);
            LoadAndDisplayFrame();
            trackBarFrames.Value = 0;
        }

        private async void VideoEditor_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            // Stop the video playback
            isVideoPlaying = false;

            // Wait for the video playback loop to finish
            while (isVideoPlaying)
            {
                await Task.Delay(100); // Adjust the delay as needed
            }

            // Release resources
            currentFrame?.Release();
            videoCapture?.Release();
            videoWriter?.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "making a video player" is not for beginners. it's more complicated than you can imagine. -- that's purely a logic problem, not an opencv problem. also: `Task.Delay` likely has a certain resolution that's tied to the system's scheduler, i.e. you can only delay in multiples of about 15.625 milliseconds (1s/64). -- simply delaying for a fixed time is not how you keep pace. for one, you need to account for other delays, and look at wall clock time, to decide how long to sleep/delay until the next frame is due to be displayed.